# ajax/jquery success response preg match content in html comments

Tags: jquery, ajax, match, response

i have ajax code.

```
success : function (data) {
    $("#div").html(data);
}
```

Its working fine, but i want to get from "data" just content in html comments. i mean:

```
<!-- begins -->
<b>some content to get</b>
<!-- ends -->
```

I need just

```
<b>some content to get</b>
```

any ideas? in php i can use preg_match or something like this, but jquery/js/ajax iam new. Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new jquery object for data and then find what content you are looking for, before adding that to the div.

To create a new jquery object: `$(data)`.

And then you can search for your content: `$(data).find('b')`.

So the final answer should look something like:

```
$('#div').html($(data).find('b'))
```

Check out the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/find/) for jquery find.